# BST insertion in c using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm new to c but have programmed in other languages. I have this piece of code for BST insertion:

```
struct tnode {
  int data;
  struct tnode* left;
  struct tnode* right;
};

struct tnode* addnode(struct tnode* root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL) return talloc(data);
    else if (data < root->data) root->left = addnode(root->left, data);
    else root->right = addnode(root->right, data);
}
```

The code works perfectly well but it's driving me crazy trying to understand how it works. I feel like it shouldn't return correctly but I've tested it extensively and it works. My gripe is when you call addnode with a root whose value isn't NULL it recursively calls addnode which returns a new tnode to root->left or root->right. This is fine. However, after the recursive call has returned the function should resume execution from that point in the original call. Then it should resume after the if-else clause. After that clause there is no return. How the hell is it returning correctly when I add multiple items?

I was trying things out and added a `puts("hello");` after the if-else clause and that messed up the entire thing and gave me a segmentation fault: 11 (whatever that means).

Comment: add talloc function also.

Comment: You should be getting compilation warnings because there is no return for the `else if` or `else` branches of the function.  You should probably have `return root;` before the `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right. The function you have is missing a return call after the else statement which would definitely give you confusion. Try using the following function:

```
struct tnode* addnode(struct tnode* root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL) return talloc(data);
    else if (data < root->data) root->left = addnode(root->left, data);
    else root->right = addnode(root->right, data);
    return root;
}
```

Let me know if this helps. Happy programming!

Comment: thanks, this makes much more sense. Any idea why the version in the OP worked? It seems so strange to me.